# Is it possible to change directory mode so that no one can create new files in it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

Say that I have the folder `/dir`. Is there a command in bash that I can use so that after performing it, no one could create new files in `/dir`?

Edit: important to mention that after performing the command, there will be same permissions to the directory files as they were before. For example, if I have folder `/dir` with file `a.txt` in it - so after I use my desired command I cant create new files, but I can modify/delete `a.txt` if I want.

Comment: look at`chmod`/`chown` commands , with first you can change access right second owner

Comment: Do not give write permission to the directory

Comment: Mark, as long as you don't use chmod -R and only chmod, the permission on the directory will change leaving the resident files in the directory unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the permission with `chmod` to only let people read the folders content.

Comment: Edited my post. I want to have same permissions for files that were in the directory before I used my desired command.

Answer (score -1):

> chmod a-w /dir

Will remove all write permissions of all (ugo), but keep x (execute) and r (read) permissions intact.

Comment: Edited my post. I want to have same permissions for files that were in the directory before I used my desired command.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's pretty simple. Just chmod to read only. Here is a sample

```
chmod -R 0444 /path/to/your/dir/
```

Where the last 3 4's mean User-readonly, Group-readonly and others-readonly respectively.

Comment: Edited my post. I want to have same permissions for files that were in the directory before I used my desired command.